# R Chi-Squared Table Format

Tags: r, statistics

So I have some data that is formatted like so:

```
header1    header2
"nocandy"  "nocandy"
"nocandy"  "nocandy"
"nocandy"  "nocandy"
"nocandy"    "candy"
"nocandy"    "candy"
"candy"    "candy"
etc...
```

I imported it with `candytext <- read.table("candytest.txt", header=TRUE)`
And I want to do a chi-squared test to see if there is a difference between the two groups.
When I use the function `table(candytest)` I get something like this:

```
         header2
header1   candy nocandy
  candy     112      39
  nocandy     4      82
```

But if I run `summary(candytest)` I get something like this:

```
    header1       header2   
 candy  :151   candy  :116  
 nocandy: 86   nocandy:121
```

As you can see the two tables are formatted differently. However, I can run a chisquared test on the first table but not the second. However the summary table is more like the table I would need to use to do a `chisq.test()` on. The second table looks like it's assuming that the data is paired, but the data is not paired. If it was paired it would be fine and I could use McNemars test on the output of `table(candytest)`, but it's not paired. So how do I create a 2 by 2 matrix that looks like the summary table, without typing it out by hand. I realise I could copy the summary table into a matrix, however I want to know how to convert it in R with functions properly.

Thank you!

Comment: `summary` is not designed to do crosstabulatons or chi-squared statistics. It does not return a table a object. It returns a text output on a column-by-column basis. Please read the help pages.

Comment: You can do `summary(table(df))` and get a chi-squared test result.  But you'll probably need to rearrange the data into groups

Comment: @RichardScriven - beware these are not the same: `summary(table(df))` is equivalent to `chisq.test(tab, correct=FALSE)`, where `correct=TRUE` is the default.

Comment: I suppose I should have written that `summary.data.frame` is not so designed.

Comment: Type `methods(summary)` to see a few other function names.

Comment: I wish I could have given all of you a checkmark. You were all very helpful in answering my novice questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am trying to get `summary` on each column of `df1` using `lapply` assuming that the column `classes` are factors.  From the post, I guess that is the case.  Using `do.call(data.frame` on the `list` output, converts it to `data.frame`.

```
  do.call(data.frame,lapply(df1, summary)) #in case a matrix output is needed, just replace `data.frame` with `cbind`
  #          header1 header2
  #candy         1       3
  #nocandy       5       3


  summary(df1)
  #   header1     header2 
  #candy  :1   candy  :3  
  #nocandy:5   nocandy:3
```

If you need only selected columns from many columns in a dataset,

```
  nm1 <- paste0("header",1:2) #names of columns to do the summary
   do.call(`cbind`, lapply(df1[nm1], summary))
   #        header1 header2
   #candy         1       3
   #nocandy       5       3
```

You could also do `summary` with `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)
  DT <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, summary)]   #or

 #DT <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, table)] 
  DT
   #    header1 header2
   #1:       1       3
   #2:       5       3

 chisq.test(DT)

 #    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

  #data:  DT
  #X-squared = 0.375, df = 1, p-value = 0.5403

  #Warning message:
  #In chisq.test(DT) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(header1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("candy", 
"nocandy"), class = "factor"), header2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("candy", "nocandy"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("header1", 
"header2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Beautiful! Now can you explain what this is doing? It looks like voodoo to me, I'm relatively new to R. Is there a better way I could have imported it, or just a better way I could do the test?

Comment: @jelijelidjango I added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to treat your columns as independent samples. If so, this might not be the best data structure. But you could do

```
#sample data
candytext<-read.table(text='header1    header2
 "nocandy"  "nocandy"
 "nocandy"  "nocandy"
 "nocandy"  "nocandy"
 "nocandy"    "candy"
 "nocandy"    "candy"
 "candy"    "candy"', header=T)

#summarize
do.call(cbind, lapply(candytext, table))
#         header1 header2
# candy         1       3
# nocandy       5       3
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it wasn't the best data structure. But I'm just getting familiar with R. What would you recommend to use? How should I have started out?

Comment: Two columns: one for the observation (ie "candy","nocandy") and one for the group ("group1" vs "group2")

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> dd = data.frame(sapply(candytext, summary))
> dd
        header1 header2
candy         1       3
nocandy       5       3

> chisq.test(dd)                
        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction                                                    

data:  dd                                                                                                               
X-squared = 0.375, df = 1, p-value = 0.5403                                                                             

Warning message:                                                                                                        
In chisq.test(dd) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect                                                          
>
```

If you want to select 2 columns from a multicolumn data frame:

```
> cc = cbind(summary(candytext$header1), summary(candytext$header2))

> cc
        [,1] [,2]
candy      1    3
nocandy    5    3

> chisq.test(cc)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  cc
X-squared = 0.375, df = 1, p-value = 0.5403

Warning message:
In chisq.test(cc) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

In following form, table and summary are same:

```
> cbind(table(candytext$header1), table(candytext$header2))
        [,1] [,2]
candy      1    3
nocandy    5    3
> 
> cbind(summary(candytext$header1), summary(candytext$header2))
        [,1] [,2]
candy      1    3
nocandy    5    3
```